# Want to duplicate css styles for an ID based style, how to do this with least duplication?

Tags: css

I have:

```
#elementA a.blah {
..
}

#elementA label {
..
}

#elementA div.some_class {
..
}
```

I know have a new ID #elementB that I want to be exactly like the styles for #elementA, how can I do this with least CSS duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way would be to have a class for those styles instead of an ID.

If that isn't possible, you could do this:

```
#elementA, #elementB {

}

#elementA label, #elementB label {

}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#elementA a.blah, #elementA label, #elementA div.some_class {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the common styles to a class instead of the ID.

```
.element a.blah {
..
}

.element label {
..
}

.element div.some_class {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give SASS a shot ;)
http://sass-lang.com/

```
#elementA, #elementB{
  a.blah {
    ..
  }

  label {
    ..
  }

  div.some_class {
    ..
  }
}
```

Sass is really quite amazing, both for it's mixin capability and for it's awesome nesting.  However as some people mentioned previously, it could make the most sense to just use a class named `.element`

But I refuse to work on any project without using Sass :p  It's so easy to setup for any static or dynamic site.

Answer (score 0):

use class, give same class name to both divs

```
<div id="elementA" class="test1">..</div>
<div id="elementB" class="test1">..</div>
```

stylesheet

```
.test1 label{....}
```

or

```
#elementA.test1 label, #elementB.test1 label{}
```